# Unity3D C# WWW class: execute code after every request

Tags: c#, web, unity-game-engine, webrequest

I couldn't find any clues for this online as I suppose a lot of people have abandoned Unity's WWW class for complex stuff. I'm using the WWW class to talk to my REST API, and I need to find a way to execute some code **after** every request. (I need to check the response code and execute some default behaviour if the response is 401)

Is there a simple way to achieve this?

(I'm using coroutines to send the requests)

Thanks in advance.

**Update: Current code sample**

Auth.cs:

```
public IEnumerator Login(WWWForm data, Action<APIResponse> success, Action<APIResponse> failure)
    {
        WWW request = new WWW (API + "auth/authenticate", data);
        yield return request;
        if (request.responseHeaders ["STATUS"] == "HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized") {
            //Do something, I want to do this on every request, not just on this login method
        }
        if (request.error != null) {
            failure (new APIResponse(request));
        }
        else {
            //Token = request.text.Replace("\"", "");
            Token = request.text;
            Debug.Log (Token);
            success (new APIResponse (request));
        }

    }
```

Usage:

```
StartCoroutine (auth.Login (data, new Action<APIResponse> (response => {
            //Do stuff

        }), new Action<APIResponse> (response => {
            //Do stuff
        })));
```

Comment: Updated my post to include some code.

Answer (score 2):

I am not using WWW with rest api to achieve the "async" way, using the time out and exception handling works for me:

```
public static string PostJson(string host, string resourceUrl, object json)
{
    var client = new RestClient(host);
    client.Timeout = Settings.LIGHT_RESPONSE_TTL; //set timeout duration

    var request = new RestRequest(resourceUrl, Method.POST);
    request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
    request.AddBody(json);

    try
    {
        var response = client.Execute(request);
        return response.Content;
    }
    catch (Exception error)
    {
        Utils.Log(error.Message);
        return null;
    }

}
```

To consume this function:

```
var result = JsonUtils.PostJson("http://192.168.1.1:8080", "SomeEndPoints/abc/def", jsonString);
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(result))
{
     //Error
}
else
{
      //Success
}
```

Update: to make sure such calls do not block the UI, use below code:

```
Loom.RunAsync(() => {
    var result = JsonUtils.PostJson("http://192.168.1.1:8080", "SomeEndPoints/abc/def", jsonString);
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(result)) {

    }
});
```

You can download Loom [here](http://www.programering.com/a/MzM1UzNwATg.html). Example use of such code can be demonstrated with below GIF animation, note that the UI (circular indicator) is not blocked!

[image]

Comment: I don't think RestSharp is supported by Unity, please correct me if I'm wrong but I don't think it will run on iOS.

Comment: It is absolutely supported, change the .net framework to 3.5. in player settings, I have done this millions of times, :). Also you should use RestSharp with the version that is compatible to .net 3.5, you can download it easily from github or elsewhere.

Comment: You might also try JsonFX!

Comment: Ah perfect! But I don't really want to block the UI when requests take a little longer than expected, do you have an example using async with this library?

Comment: If you run this  in non ui  thread, it will  not block the  ui at all.  I do have an example  which shows a circular indicator when json is posted.

Comment: Ah I understand, an example would be highly appreciated :)

Comment: @TristanGodfrey, non-blocking calling example updated.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response @David , I'll get back to you once I've tried this.

Comment: I can only choose .NET 2.0 subset or .NET 2.0 on the iOS player settings (api compatibility level), I'm using Unity 5.2.0f3. Am I missing something?

Comment: Choose .Net 2.0, which corresponds to Mono 3.5

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91746/discussion-between-tristan-godfrey-and-david).