# How to get data from an OPC server in Unity3d

Tags: .net, unity-game-engine, server, connection, opc

I want to retrieve data (value of variables) from a program using an OPC server to do so.  The idea is to be able to read the value of the variables and to overwrite it as well. I want to do it in Unity3d.

I've been searching in many websites and stackoverflow of course, but I'm not able to find the solution for my problem.

What I've done so far is using the OPC server "KEPServerEX 5", retrieve information from the desired program. In unity I wrote few scripts in C# using opclabs libraries but the problem is that they and Unity don't share compatibility with .Net Framework (Unity uses v2.0 and these libraries v4.5). Consequently, I cannot use those libraries and get data from the OPC server. I read something about making a bridge with phyton to get the job done but no idea.

Did anybody have to deal with such a problem? Would you know how to do it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: have you familiaried yourself with using `WWW` etc, to get info from the net?  http://stackoverflow.com/a/33013590/294884

Answer (score 0):

.NET is backwards compatible.
Do you get errors with the compiler regarding this issue?

And I don not get one part. 
As far I understand your project, you want to read out data from the OPC Server. This means you're going to implement an OPC Client in your code.
OPC Server is Kepware. OPC Client is Unity. This has nothing to do with the libraries or programming language. OPC is a protocol between the Server and Client.
There can be several reasons why they can not communicate is that one could be OPC Classic and the other one OPC UA. Or OPC Classic on both sides, but a release of the OPC Classic standard.
Test with an official client if the server is working. Especially with OPC Classic you can have issues regarding DCOM and user rights. And readout the return values from OPC.

http://www.advosol.com/OpcErrorLookup.aspx
http://www.opcfoundation.org (perfect base for all your OPC questions)

Comment: Thank you for your reply!

I was able to solve the problem regarding the libraries by using an earlier version of them. However, I checked the OPC server with an OPC client and it is working properly. I am able to assure that because I can force variables in the external program and see how they change with the OPC client through the OPC server.
This KEPServerEX 5 KEPServerEX supports OPC UA and many of the OPC Classic specifications, OPC DA, OPC AE and OPC HDA. Consequently, I understand that type of OPC shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem partially, so maybe my solution will be useful for someone with a similar problem.
What we did is to use Cogent Datahub to connect with the OPC Server. Now we are working with a database to connect Cogent Datahub with Unity3D and it seems feasible.